# Initializing Hibernate takes lot of time in Sonar analysis

Tags: hibernate, sonarqube, static-code-analysis

I am using Sonar for static code analysis in my project. The issue is Sonar is taking lot of time at the point **Initializing Hibernate**. Does anyone has any idea about how to speed up sonar analysis?

Answer (score 0):

We're progressively pulling Hibernate out of Sonar, but for the moment you just can't get rid of it.

When you say "a lot of time", how much to you mean? This shouldn't take minutes.

Comment: Side issue to the original question - what are you using instead of Hibernate?